# Restricting selection to entire row/column in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I need a way to only allow the user to select a row or a column (or multiple selection of entire rows, and entire columns) using handsontable.

Comment: The Eternal question, What have you tried?

Comment: I've answered my own question :) I thought it would be good to share.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research and experimentation, I was able to achieve single-row highlighting without the cell and row handles.

Handsontable options:

```
var x = new Handsontable(element, {
    ...
    multiSelect: false,
    disableVisualSelection: ['current', 'area'],
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow'
}
```

CSS:

```
.currentRow, .highlight {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an way to select multiple cells, range cells and even single cell by setting: `selectionMode='multiple'` checkout this link: https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/3.0.0/Options.html#selectionMode

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
beforeOnCellMouseDown: function restrictSelectionToWholeRowColumn(event, coords) {
  if(coords.row >= 0 && coords.col >= 0) event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

works like charm!